# Visual Studio 2017: The SDK resolver type "DotNetMSBuildSdkResolver" failed to load

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I've just upgraded Visual Studio Community 2017 to the latest version (15.9.2).
I tried creating a new ASP.NET Core Web Application project. Although the project files got created ok, the project won't load into the Visual Studio Solution Explorer - when I try to load the project, VS shows the following message:

The SDK resolver type "DotNetMSBuildSdkResolver" failed to load. The type initializer for 'Microsoft.DotNet.MSBuildSdkResolver.VSSettings' threw an exception.

I have .NET Core SDK 2.1.500 installed.

Any ideas why this is happening? Unfortunately this is preventing me from working with this project.

(By the way - creating a ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework) (i.e. NOT core) works fine.

Comment: Same here. Can't open any existing asp.net core projects

Answer (score 3):

I had to install the [32bit version of the .net core sdk](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download).  Then the project loaded fine.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue today, my envs: win10, VS2017 15.9.4

Just use "**Repair**" of **visual studio installer**, and after that it works!

Answer (score 0):

Had same error for the last few day.
I found a temporary workaround this problem - starting Visual Studio as Administrator

Comment: That didn't work for me. However, I've installed VS2017 on a different machine now (Windows 10 instead of Windows Server 2008) and that is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be an issue that's been introduced in the latest Visual Studio 2017 release. On my Windows Server 2008 system (where I was having the issue), I uninstalled 15.9.2 and installed the previous version 15.8.9 - that version worked fine. I.e. I can now load all my ASP.NET Core projects into the solution. (To be sure, I reinstalled 15.9.2 and confirmed that that that version definitely still did not work).